# Brand new build TWICE, same issue

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard

Alright so I am extremely frustrated with this computer build, to the point I may never build another one again. About 2 weeks ago I bought all new computer parts to build a new one, and I had issues with it not booting because of the "cpu" LED being on. Note I bought a NEW MOTHERBOARD thinking it was dead.

So I went on here, asked a question, and bought a new CPU. Now I am having THE SAME issue I had before, the CPU led is on. Before the cpu light came on, the boot light was on. I read in the MOBO manual that you need to power off the computer without unplugging it to reset the cmos, but go figure I can't do that because my power button for some reason turns the computer on but not off.

I am beyond frustrated with this computer and all I want for it to do is work, it's stressing me out with all the problems from day 1. After buying not only a new CPU, but a new MOBO as well the same problem persists.

EDIT: I would like to point out randomly none of the debug LED's are one, but it still doesn't boot.

Computer parts:
- MSI B350 Gaming Plus MOBO
- Ryzen 5 1500x CPU
- Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1050 Ti
- 120 GB SSD
- 500W PSU

If anyone has the miracle solution please help me out, I just need answers.

Comment: Did you try a different PSU like was suggested in your other question?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing changed

Comment: The firmware the motherboard is the current revision?

Comment: There is normally a Reset button on MSI motherboards

Comment: No reset button on mine, I tried clearing the CMOS but I don't know if it worked or not. I used a screw-driver but that didn't seem to work. In the user guide it says use a CMOS Jumper but I don't have one.

Comment: Yes; You do; If the manual references one it exists

Comment: If you can tell me where it is I will gladly press it, because I don't see it :/

Comment: Any luck finding out? I haven't been able to find any reset button.